# Rule - Check for empty email body & auto delete them

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-web-app

I have no idea why outlook allows many potential **phishing** emails to flow through.

I see no message text... they mostly containing on an image if we click on that image, it's a trap to go to their malicious site.

[image]

I would like to query these kind of mails with empty body, and auto **delete** them.

Comment: Added : I am using the web app version, if anyone know how to do that, please kindly suggested

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/bb430785(v=exchg.141)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Right from the article:

"**The ^$ Regular Expression**

To detect messages that have blank subject lines, the following procedures use the ^$ regular expression. This regular expression consists of two pattern strings, ^ and $. Pattern strings are used in regular expressions to match patterns in text that can vary. When the ^ and $ pattern strings are used in this order, the transport rule condition matches only the exact string that's between the two pattern strings. Because there's no string between the ^ and $ pattern strings in the ^$ regular expression, it matches only an empty string, such as a blank subject line."

Comment: This is all very well for a server admin, but how to do it as a regular user?

Comment: The idea is to use this logic to set up mail flow rules to quarantine or at least report emails that match this for review. I am not sure why standard users would want to utilize this unless you are talking about using it for Outlook rules.

Comment: Yes ... isn't the question about Outlook rules? In any case, I have that question about Outlook rules.